# How to parse binary_compressed point cloud?

Tags: javascript, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to parse binary_compressed point cloud file in javascript.

I found, that in [writeBinaryCompressed()](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp#L1610) points are 'Convert the XYZRGBXYZRGB structure to XXYYZZRGBRGB to aid compression', but I don't understand what does in mean. Also, I found that in [parsing method](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp#L933) points 
'Unpack the xxyyzz to xyz'.

What does it mean? How to parse points after decompression?

Comment: Hi, @tom, did you solve your problem? I have a similar problem with a binary compressed PCD. All point look okay but I have a problem with the color. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PCL, point clouds are represented as an array of structures (AoS), meaning that all fields of a point go one after another in the memory, followed by the fields of the next point, and so on. This is in contrast to the structure of arrays (SoA) layout, where first all x coordinates of each point are written, then all y coordinates, and so on. You can find more information and motivation for these layouts in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA).

That being said, I have an implementation of a PCD file loader for three.js that can handle binary compressed format, you may find it [here](https://gitlab.com/taketwo/three-pcd-loader). Specifically, decompression and unpacking happens in [lines 96-112](https://gitlab.com/taketwo/three-pcd-loader/blob/master/pcd-loader.js#L96-112).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Have you tested your implementation of binary compressed models parsing by opening test data by three.js? You parsing binary compressed as AoS, but I think it's written as SoA and we must parse it as SoA. I've opened xyzrgb_binary_compressed.pcd model by three.js with your implementation:[pic](http://prntscr.com/f81rnb), and with my:[pic](http://prntscr.com/f81rhr) . As you can see, points positions with your implementation are wrong. My [implementation on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Ej2hmy8w) Am I right?

Comment: But even with my implementation, I can't open binary compressed models from [pcd dataset](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pointclouds/files/PCD%20datasets/). I have NaNs in coordinates while parsing model.

Comment: Well there is this `data/` folder and associated unit tests; they pass on my machine. Last year this loader was used in production and IIRC with compressed files as well. Unfortunately it's been a while and I do not have any time to look into this now.

Comment: Regarding AoS/SoA: no, in binary compressed mode I indeed parse as SoA, please pay attention to how the offset variable is initialized.